NextJS layout is getting overriden by parent layout
Here's is the structure of my NextJS project:
├── app
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── login
│   │   │   ├── layout.js
│   │   │   └── page.js
│   │   ├── users
│   │   │   └── page.js
│   │   ├── layout.js
│   │   └── page.js
│   ├── layout.js
│   └── page.js

For some reason, it throws error saying "Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in " when you access localhost:3000/admin/login. When I tried removing layout.js from login directory, the error was gone. I also tried editing the layout.js from admin directory and the changes is also showing in /admin/login page.

/admin/login/page.js
export default function Page() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello Login</h1>
    );
}

/admin/login/layout.js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
    title: "Create Next App",
    description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function LoginLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}

Admin also has the same codes for both layout.js and page.js

The nested layout does not overwrite the parent layout it ads to it, so you are basically rendering your html and body tags within another html and body tag.

Does this answer your question? Layout styles not persisting on refresh
